Should launching background jobs cause a race condition?
I tested the following with both bash and dash, and it seems to reliably hang:
[ -p pipe ] || mkfifo pipe

i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
  <pipe cat &
  : $(( i+=1 ))
done

# sleep 1
echo hello world >pipe
wait

If we lower the limit from 10 to 1, it doesn't hang (at least not reliably). Sleeping keeps it from hanging.
I think that the echo is happening before all background jobs have opened the pipe, so EOF is written to the pipe, closing the pipe and terminating some background jobs. The late arrivals then get stuck waiting for an EOF that never comes.
Is this expected behavior? It sure looks like a bug to me, but I'm not sure whether it's my bug or the shell's.
Also: I know I can just write echo x | { <launch commands here> }, and that would be neater, but I'm working around some dash behavior I've already reported as a bug.
EDIT: The version below terminates consistently in bash, so it seems likely that it is intended to be possible to launch a group of background processes and feed them from a single pipeline without doing anything special.
echo hello world | {
  i=0
  while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
    cat &
    : $(( i+=1 ))
  done
}
wait

EDIT: opening the pipe in the parent (r/w mode to avoid blocking) and duplicating the resulting file descriptor for each background process does not seem to solve the issue and results in hangs even after sleeping.
[ -p pipe ] || mkfifo pipe
exec 3<>pipe

i=0
while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
  <&3 cat &
  : $(( i+=1 ))
done

# sleep 1
echo hello world >pipe
wait


I just tried with just 2 background jobs and got three hangs in a row. It may be a weird interaction with my setup, but it's weird this happens at all. My mental model of an async list is that, after it runs, the background job exists in some well defined state.

The main problem is truncating the file with >; if you use >> then all works well even in dash

Another issue is that I don't see how I'd do the locking. My first instinct is "lockfiles" (have each worker create a file of the form /tmp/$$-$workerid, signifying that it's good to go), but:

I can't create a file before running cat, or I'm not actually good to go
I can't create it at the same time because race condition
I can't create it after, because I'm blocking on cat


Sorry, @Fravadona, I just tried that, in both bash and dash with 10 background processes, and it hung for both.

If you group the commands with { cmd1; cmd2; ...; <pipe cat; } & then you can execute whatever you want before the cat. That said, locking should be done using a single "lockfile" for every process; if you use flock then that could directly be the pipe; if you prefer more a rudimentary method then you could create a symlink (as their creation is guaranteed to be atomic)

Right, but { touch /tmp/lockfile; <pipe cat; } & would only exacerbate the race condition. The lockfile that says "cat is ready to go" is created before cat is launched, which delays cat's ready state and sends a false signal that it's ready.

Strange, the script was hanging in dash with only two processes when using >, but with >> it works with at least 10000. You might have to kill the previously spwaned processes that are still around, or delete the pipe file before testing the script

a basic lock would be { until ln -s pipe pipe.lock; do sleep 1; done; <pipe cat; rm pipe.lock; } &

I just turned my computer off and back on again, copied the script into a new directory, changed the redirection to >>, ran it with 10 workers, and it hung on the second try.

But that lock doesn't properly lock. The parent process is going to wait until all lock files are present, then write the data. But the parent could have checked at a point where all locks have been created but some instances of cat still haven't opened the pipe.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

This question was jointly answered by Greg Wooledge and Chet Ramey over in the GNU "bash-help" mailing list.
In summary, there are two reasons this doesn't work:

POSIX leaves unspecified the behavior of multiple concurrent reads on the same pipe, and
redirections into background jobs are performed at the kernel scheduler's leasure, so order of operations should not be relied upon.

With a single pipe everything works fine because processes will stop until both ends of the connection are open.
Multiple concurrent reads/writes happen to work on Linux, but this is not portable behavior.

You'd have to trace that to see for sure what order everything ends up happening (e.g. with strace on Linux), but note that there's no ordering between how the background processes run and the rest of the shell script runs. It's quite possible for some of the later background processes to run after the echo in the main script has finished. This will depend heavily on the OS and the surrounding environment.
So what you may get is something like this:
<pipe cat # bg 1
...
<pipe cat # bg N
echo hello world >pipe
<pipe cat # bg N+1
...
<pipe cat # bg N+M

Here, the first N cats, or rather, the shell processes about to launch the cats block when trying to open the pipe as there's no writer yet. Then the shell about to run echo opens the write side of the pipe, letting the cats finish their opens. The echo writes, one cat reads, and when the echo finishes, all cats see the pipe is now closed as it has no writer; they read an EOF and exit. Then after that, the last M background processes get around to trying to open the pipe, and block on open since there's no writer.

Here,
echo hello world | {
  i=0
  while [ $i -lt 10 ]; do
    cat &
    : $(( i+=1 ))
  done
}
wait

the pipe is created once, and the same already-open fd is passed to all cats. It's not opened for each cat individually, so none of them block on open. If some of the cats get around to reading the fd before the echo has written anything, they'll block on read waiting for data. When the left-hand side closes the pipe, all cats read an EOF, even the ones that first read their copy of the fd after the echo had finished.

I tried the following version, and it hangs, even when sleeping. Duplicating the parent's file descriptor to the background jobs doesn't seem to be enough, you have to use an anonymous pipe (which breaks with dash). [code moved to question body]
